# create test plan for a certain tag group in rally

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am new user to Rally.We have bunch of test cases for our project and they have tags.I would like to create test folders for each tag, thus enabling me to create test plans for any iteration by choosing certain test cases from each tag group. is there any easy solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

MarkW has an app (in [this github repo](https://github.com/markwilliams970/Tagged-Defects-AllProjects)) that uses a tag picker and builds a grid of defects filtered by tags. I expanded on this app by changing the workitem to TestCase, and added a  functionality to create test folders named after selected tags. 
You may see the full code in a [github repo here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/tag-picker-folder-creator).

Here is a method that creates testfolders after making sure that a folder with same names does not yet exist:

```
_createTestFolders: function(){
        var me = this;
        console.log(me._existingFoldersNames);
        Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'TestFolder',
            success: function(model) {  
                _.each(me._tagNames, function(tagName){
                    var exists = _.find(me._existingFoldersNames, function(existingName){return tagName === existingName});
                        if (exists === undefined) {
                            var folder = Ext.create(model, {
                                Name: tagName
                            });
                            folder.save({
                                callback: function(result, operation) {
                                    if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                                        console.log("Created TestFolder: _ref",result.get('_ref'), ' ', result.get('Name'));
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        console.log("error");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                });
            }
        });
    }
```